# create a shortcut for changing style sheet in Safari

Tags: css, safari, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts

Safari doesn’t have build-in “dark theme” or night mode extension like Chrome, so it really hurts when I need to do homework in a dark room (when my roommates are sleeping). Thankfully Safari can change its default css sheet in preference. So I wrote something as follows,

```
* {
color: rgb(176, 176,176) !important;

background: #000000  !important;
}

a:link {
color: rgb(99,202,67)!important;
}
```

It generally works great but I need to switch the style sheet repeatedly specially when it is not textual material.

So I am wondering how to create a shortcut for switching the style sheet?
What about using **AppleScript**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have quite a few settings in various apps that I toggle between two states regularly and use AppleScript to automate the task. I personally try not to use UI Scripting if possible, as it can have its issues however, in your particular case I believe a UI Scripting solution with AppleScript is how it will need to be accomplished.

That said, if Safari was closed the changes that are made to the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist file when going through the UI probably could also be done using the `defaults` command and then opening Safari. However, I'd assume you'd want to be able to make this change on the fly with Safari open and not having to close/reopen to accomplish the task, hence UI Scripting.

I took the code in your question and saved it as MyStyleSheet.css.

I then manually went through the process of setting it as the style sheet under: Safari > Preferences… > Advanced > Style sheet:

With that done, I set it back to None Selected and then wrote this AppleScript script:

Example AppleScript code:

```
if not running of application "Safari" then
    display dialog "Safari is not open." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
    return
end if

tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        click menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Preferences…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
        click UI element "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of window 1
    end tell
    tell group 1 of group 1 of window "Advanced" of application process "Safari"
        set currentStyleSheet to (value of pop up button 1)
        click pop up button 1
        if currentStyleSheet contains "None Selected" then
            click menu item "MyStyleSheet" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
        else
            click menu item "None Selected" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
        end if
    end tell
    click button 1 of window "Advanced" of application process "Safari"
end tell
```

I saved the above example AppleScript code as an AppleScript application named Toggle Safari Style Sheet, and tested that it works as intended. Note that there can be a time delay in closing Safari Preferences after the style sheet is changed. The lag time is dependent on how may Safari windows are open and other activity occurring on the system at the same time. This delay was that same whether making the change manually or using AppleScript.

---

Note that the example AppleScript code is just that and is meant to show a way of accomplishing a given task. The onus is upon the user to add any appropriate error handling as necessary and additional `delay` commands as may be needed.

Comment: I am so impressed, thanks! Let me test it out. @user3439894

Comment: Could you explain the last line "click button 1 of window "Advanced" of application process "Safari"" ? I know this is to activate the main window again, but what is "button 1"?  (Sorry for the long-delayed question....)

Comment: It's the close button in the upper left corner of the window.